Http request c# how to get external ip when request completed
I try to get ip and port from request which completed and Idk how to do it
Problem:
I have router in which I configure that from adress1 to adress2 I want to send from first external ip
From adress1 to adress3 I want send data from second external ip
And How I can get Ip and Port when request completed?
How to do it with:
 using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler())
 {

     using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
     {
         HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, recipientUrl);
      }
}


If your router does that the router is the one that knows what and why he did it. A good router should have a log for that you can look at. But the actual taken route from you to a target system is not part of a http response. There might be routers/gateways/firewalls that add their own custom headers to requests/responses but that is totally propritary and you need find that out via the routers documentation if there is something
